# Recovering the saved VM

Tags: virtualbox, images

ALL,

I made a VirtualBox VM on the external USB HDD.

Then I closed as "Saved" and disconnected the HDD.

Now, I connected drive but when I try to open the VM back up it errors out:

```
VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file.
```

Is there a way to recover and open the VM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like in all such cases I would create an image (full copy) of the USB HDD immediately, before you start recovery attempts that may harm the recoverability.

The easiest apporach would be to check the file system of the USB HDD, but this might also just remove the remains of the file metadata, that is why an image should be done beforehand.

You miss quite some required information for more details, like the operating system (Windows, Linux, MacOS and the distribution/version) you use, the file system that is used on the USB HDD and information about which files of the VM are still shown on the USB HDD by your file manager.

In general, it may be possible that the image is alright, but cannot be found by virtual box, e.g. because it is looking at the wrong place.